# react router not showing component on url update

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

probably a simple question for most but, why isn't my component rendering when my url updates, when I update the url manually it works but the links i'm using do not?

I have included my links component below, the display bar should display as a nav (so on every route) but the Newcase component should only display on its specified route. I have tried using the exact prop on it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route,Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class DisplayBar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <div>
             <Router>
                <Link to="/">home</Link>
                <Link to="/form">form</Link>
            </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

and here is my router in my main app.js

```
render(){
    return (

      <Router>

        <Route path = '/' component ={DisplayBar} />
        <switch>
          <Route exact path='/form' component = {NewCase} />
        </switch> 

      </Router>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap your links with Router, Remove `Router`

```
                <Link to="/">home</Link>
                <Link to="/form">form</Link>
```

and also put `<Route path = '/' component ={DisplayBar} />` inside switch

```
<switch>
  <Route path = '/' component ={DisplayBar} />
  <Route exact path='/form' component = {UserAdd} />
</switch>
```

Comment: Oops! Thanks! I’ll try this out.